# Splitting string elements of an array in python to characters

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, split

I'm still new in Python and solution might be simple however I feel stuck. I have an array likes this:

```
array([['one two'],
       ['three four'],
       ['five six'],
       ['seven eight']], dtype='<U9')
```

I can't figure out how to split it to make it look like this:

```
array([['o', 'n', 'e', 't', 'w', 'o'],
       ['t', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'o', 'u', 'r'],
       ['f', 'i', 'v', 'e', 's', 'i', 'x'],
       ['s', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'n', 'e', 'i', 'g', 'h', 't']])
```

I tried splitting it while converting this array to a list however I couldn't figure it out how to convert it back to an array like the one above. Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Is the dtype correct? Just by storing the first array like this, you are limiting the length of the strings to 5 characters, e.g. 'one two' will be stored as 'one t'

Answer (score 1):

It's quite uncommon to see `array` used in vanilla python - `list` is much more widespread. But with lists you would have done `a = list([list(item[0]) for item in a])`.
`list("abc") == ["a", "b", "c"]`, since string is an iterable of its characters. `array` should work almost the same, except you should handle the `dtype` attribute as well.